# append a list into end of list in list

Tags: python, list, 2d

Is there a good way to 'merge' 2 lists together so an item in one list can be appended to the end of a list in a list? For example...

```
a2dList=[['a','1','2','3','4'],['b','5','6','7','8'],[........]]
otherList = [9,8,7,6,5]

theFinalList=[['a','1','2','3','4',9],['b','5','6','7','8',8],[....]]
```

I'm not sure if it matter that a2dList is made of strings and otherList are numbers...
I've tried `append` but I end up with

```
theFinalList=[['a','1','2','3','4'],['b','5','6','7','8'],[.......],[9,8,7,6,5]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> a2dList=[['a','1','2','3','4'],['b','5','6','7','8']]
>>> otherList = [9,8,7,6,5]
>>> for x, y in zip(a2dList, otherList):
        x.append(y)


>>> a2dList
[['a', '1', '2', '3', '4', 9], ['b', '5', '6', '7', '8', 8]]
```

On Python 2.x consider using `itertools.izip` instead for lazy zipping:

```
from itertools import izip # returns iterator instead of a list
```

Also note that `zip` will automatically stop upon reaching the end of the shortest iterable, so if `otherList` or `a2dList` had only `1` item, this solution would work without error, modifying lists by index risks these potential problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
>>> b = [5,6]
>>> for index,element in enumerate(b):
        a[index].append(element)


>>> a
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: if b is larger than a, it crashes

Comment: This worked perfect, but thanks to all. If I can go a little further...I now need to create another list to only hold items from the appended 'a2dList' if the number I just added to the end of each list is less than a certain value ie. for item in a2dList: if item<7: shortList.append(item) ... but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
zip(*zip(*a2dList)+[otherList])
```